# How to launch multiple operations in a loop using multithreading c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

## Introduction

I am trying to launch 4 functions in parallel: `func1, func2, func3` and `func4` on a `6` cores machine. Every function will iterate for 1000 times an fill vector entities.  The main function is `do_operations()`. I have two versions of `do_operations()` which I posted in section **source code**.

---

### Problem

By using the first version I get the following error:

```
std::system_error'
what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
```

In order to solve that problem. I added a condition in the `version 2`. If the number of threads is equal to **6** which is the number of the cores that I have. Then I run the threads and clear `vector<thread> threads`.

Am I writing the threading function correctly? what am I doing wrong.

---

### Source code

```
void my_class::func1(std::vector<std::string> & entities)
{
  for(int = 0; i < 1000;i++)
  {
      mtx.lock();
      entities.push_back(to_string(i));
      mtx.unlock();
  }
}

void my_class::func2(std::vector<std::string> & entities)
{
  for(int = 0; i < 1000;i++)
  {
      mtx.lock();
      entities.push_back(to_string(i));
      mtx.unlock();
  }
}


void my_class::func3(std::vector<std::string> & entities)
{
  for(int = 0; i < 1000;i++)
  {
      mtx.lock();
      entities.push_back(to_string(i));
      mtx.unlock();
  }
}

void my_class::func4(std::vector<std::string> & entities)
{  
  for(int = 0; i < 1000;i++)
  {
      mtx.lock();
      entities.push_back(to_string(i));
      mtx.unlock();
  }
}
```

---

### Version 1

```
void my_class::do_operations()
{
   //get number of CPUS 
   int concurentThreadsSupported = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
   std::vector<std::thread> threads; 
   std::vector<std::string> entities;
    for(int i =0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func1, this, ref(entities)));
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func2, this, ref(entities)));
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func3, this, ref(entities)));
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func4, this, ref(entities)));
    }
    
    for(auto &t : threads){ t.join(); }
    threads.clear();
}
```

---

### Version 2

```
void my_class::do_operations()
{
   //get number of CPUS 
   int concurentThreadsSupported = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
   std::vector<std::thread> threads; 
   std::vector<std::string> entities;
    for(int i =0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func1, this, ref(entities)));
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func2, this, ref(entities)));
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func3, this, ref(entities)));
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&my_class::func4, this, ref(entities)));
        
          if((threads.size() == concurentThreadsSupported) || (i == 999))
          {
               for(auto &t : threads){ t.join(); }
              threads.clear();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're launching 4000 threads!

Comment: even in the second one?

Comment: yes, `concurentThreadsSupported` is not a multiple of 4, so the equality test never passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are launching in total 4000 threads. If every thread gets 1MB stack space, then only the threads will occupy 4000MB of address space. My assumption is that you do not have full 4GB of 32-bit address space reserved for applications (something must be left for kernel and hardware). My second assumption is that if there is not enough space to allocate a new stack, it will return the message you are seeing.

Comment: I really didn't understand the problem with the second version. What is wrong with the second one

Comment: The equality should be changed to greater-than. Just run the iterations in your head: first iteration will create 4 threads, concurentThreadsSupported is 6. They are not equal, then continue. Next iteration will create another 4 threads, in total they are 8 now. concurentThreadsSupported is still 6, these two numbers are therefore not equal, continue. Then you have 12, 16, 20, etc...

Comment: one last question Please. I corrected  `concurentThreadsSupported`  to **4**.  Do you think that there is still something wrong with the code?

Comment: Functionally it will do what you expect, but the overall design can use some rethinking. Is is really necessary to have exactly four threads per batch? If you are on a dual-core, this is too much. Is you are on a haxe-core, two cores are having a day off.